# In Smash Up, do I have to execute an effect when a card is played or can I choose to do it later in the turn?

Tags: smash-up

Fairy Circle from Pretty Pretty Smash Up says

> After the first time you play a minion here each turn, you may play an extra minion here or play an extra action

Do I have to play that minion **immediately** or can I just queue it up as "I can play another minion but I'll do a bunch of other things first?"

I would imagine the ruling on this to be in line with whatever ruling would apply to things you can do as a function of abilities on action and minion cards as well, i.e. any cards that say to play extra minions/actions, or other consequences for that matter. Do these have to take effect before any other actions are taken, or do they get to be queued up and their order of execution selected as desired?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect resolves on the spot, giving you a *floating* extra play. However, if it's not your main play phase (i.e. specials during scoring) you must use the extra play immediately.

From the most recent rulebook ([Pretty Pretty Smash Up](http://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2014/11/SU7_Rulebook.pdf)):

> **Extra:** An extra minion or action is one you can play in addition to the normal quota of one of that type per turn. Extra cards are optional, and you don’t have to play the extra card right away, unless the extra card was gained by a Special ability or outside the Play Cards phase.

This is explicitly different during scoring:

> If you get to play extra minions or actions while a base is being scored, you must play those extra cards immediately or not at all.

Comment: [Reference](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1023233/hidden-ninja-chronomage)

Answer (score 2):

The effect is resolved immediately.  But in this case, the effect is to add 1 to the total number of minions that can be played. And you can play actions and minions in any order you like.

So no, you don't have to play the minion immediately.

Comment: Is this mentioned somewhere that wording pertaining to playing extra minions and actions is to imply "in any order", but all other effects are immediate? I'd love to see the source in case other related edge cases come up.

Comment: In the smash-up rules there is a whole section on conflicting rules. And there are some tie breakers given.  
This is using common sense. And thinking in the flow of the game.  So sorry, no references.